# return the graph structure of a Neo4j cypher query using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, neo4j

based on The [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/#_presentation_svg_based_graph_interaction), executing:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit
  {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH path = (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN path",
                  "resultDataContents":["graph","row"]}]}
```

in the neo4j browser returns the graph structure plus the rows. I wonder how can I specify (`"resultDataContents":["graph","row"]`) in a jQuery ajax request. I have tried this which doesn't work:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    accepts: { json: "application/json" },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "query" : "MATCH (n)--(m) RETURN n,m LIMIT 2", "params": {"resultDataContents":["graph","row"]} })
});
```

Essentially I want to build a neo4j browser clone where I can submit queries and receive the results  and perhaps visualize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the whole procedure from query to obtaining the nodes and links of the graph.

Note that the neo4j [docs](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) (Converting Neo4j Query Results to D3 JSON) has an error : replace `start` with `source` and `end` with `target` if you want to use the graph for force directed layout.

```
// The query
var query= {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH p=(n)-->(m)<--(k),(n)--(k) RETURN p Limit 100",
    "resultDataContents":["graph","row"]}]};

//the helper function provided by neo4j documents
function idIndex(a,id) {
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a[i].id == id) return i;}
    return null;
}
// jQuery ajax call
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
    accepts: { json: "application/json" },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(query),
    //now pass a callback to success to do something with the data
    success: function (data) {
        // parsing the output of neo4j rest api
        data.results[0].data.forEach(function (row) {
            row.graph.nodes.forEach(function (n) {
                if (idIndex(nodes,n.id) == null){
                    nodes.push({id:n.id,label:n.labels[0],title:n.properties.name});
                }
            });
            links = links.concat( row.graph.relationships.map(function(r) {
                // the neo4j documents has an error : replace start with source and end with target
                return {source:idIndex(nodes,r.startNode),target:idIndex(nodes,r.endNode),type:r.type};
            }));
        });
        var graph = {nodes:nodes, links:links};

        // Now do something awesome with the graph!

    }

});
```

Comment: What is "nodes" supposed to reference here: `if (idIndex(nodes,n.id) == null){`? I'm assuming just a global array.

Comment: @PeteyB   yeah it's missing a declaration `var nodes=[], links=[];`

Answer (score 4):

The result data formats are only available through the cypher http transactional endpoint : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format

Which is the one used by the neo4j browser. Notice the difference between the two urls you mention.

Comment: Thanks. How can I send an XHR to those endpoints ? How does Neo4j Browser do it ? Can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: RTFM mate, this is just the data sent that is slightly different from the legacy Cypher endpoint. The json data looks like this (as mentioned in the documentation) {
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "CREATE ( bike:Bike { weight: 10 } ) CREATE ( frontWheel:Wheel { spokes: 3 } ) CREATE ( backWheel:Wheel { spokes: 32 } ) CREATE p1 = (bike)-[:HAS { position: 1 } ]->(frontWheel) CREATE p2 = (bike)-[:HAS { position: 2 } ]->(backWheel) RETURN bike, p1, p2",
    "resultDataContents" : [ "row", "graph" ]
  } ]
}

Comment: Please post the actual endpoint urls you are comparing instead of links to docs.  The link you provided is out of date.

Comment: Sure, then what, if after 2 years the endpoint changed also ?